# Detecting vulnerabilities for SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I read about SQL injections and the classic methods to do them. I have also come across some tools like Burp-suite. However, the material seems quite outdated. Can you provide me some pointers on good material on SQL injections ? Note this is purely for educational purposes and is part of a hacking contest.

Thanks.

Comment: People more than likely wont help you to learn SQL injection, more to help you learn how to prevent it. Even if it is for educational purposes.

Comment: Always use prepared statement with mysqli or PDO then you are almost safe.

Comment: Learn the basics first before you jump onto PDO or something else. PDO /mysqli cannot protect you from SQL injection if you do the basics wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts you want to consider:

1. Finding as much information as you can. about the script
2. Actually exploiting it.

Jihnesh was talking about the first part. In the example Jignesh gave, you find out that the script is using MySQL, information about the server / files, and that he doesn't check the category parameter as an int (because he would do something to treat this situation, instead the query was ran, and the result (expected to be an array) - is probably empty).

There are many methods for this first part, but I recommend you to check [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/) - it's a very awesome program I use for checking my websites.

Moving on to the actual "hacking" - the most basic example is the one with the users:

```
URL: login.php | POST info: user = "admin' OR 1 -- "
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '{$_POST[user]}' AND password = {$_POST[pass]}";
SQL: SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'admin' OR 1 -- ' AND password = ''
Result: Selects all the users in the users table
```

You can also check this tutorial http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html